# Popular operatic aria, sung with a lot of "ohs"

Tags: identify-this-song, opera

It's a very popular opera song. Unfortunately, I do not know of any details apart from I know that a lady sings it very high and it goes like this:

> Ohh oh oh oh oh oh oh oh oh ohh
>   Ohh oh oh oh oh oh oh oh oh ohh
>   Ohh ohohohuh ohohohuh...

Notes:
`E F G G G G G G G G C

C D E E E E E E E E A

A B C C C G D D D G`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the ["Queen of the Night"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuBeBjqKSGQ&t=39s) aria from *The Magic Flute* by Mozart.

If you listen to the above link, the part you list is at 0:39.